# Android socket reusage

Tags: android, sockets, android-activity, android-intent, parcelable

Is there a way other then, open/close sockets, when u use sockets on multiple activity's within the app?

Can I somehow send a instance of a object to the new activity(the class uses activity object from parent), and change them?
use a service?

What would bee the best way to use same socket on multiple activity's

Answer (score 0):

You could just put all the network communication in a single [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) and access that single service from all the separate activities. Also, make sure that you do all your network communication on a different thread than the UI thread. Try using an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html). If you do do your network communication on the UI thread, your going to slow down you app and probably get Application Not Responding messages.

Comment: i cannot use services, because i need to send the activity object as a parameter.

Comment: You're sending the activity over a socket?

Comment: no, i send the activity object for context etc to a class(for communication), and when i change activity's throughout the app, socket stay opened...i would like to open them once, not every time a activity is started